# Custom DirectShow graph source filter

Tags: video, directshow

All I need to do is play an AVI video from memory. I can't write it to disk for security reasons. As far as I know, the built-in AVI playing graph you get from calling `RenderFile` will only play files.

Is there a DirectShow graph that will play an AVI from memory? If not, how can I modify or create a graph that will do so?

Answer (score 5):

The graph has a source filter, demux and then decoders and renderers. The source filter is just a wrapper around the file access APIs. If you replace the stock source filter with a custom one, you can play from memory, or from whatever storage your custom filter accesses.

There is a sample source filter in the sdk which reads the whole file into memory and uses that.

G